# How to compute std::hash<> for a binary-tree data structure?

Tags: c++11, hash, binary-tree, unordered-set

I was thinking to store trees in an `std::unordered_set` in order to pick the unique trees from a collection of trees. If my tree node has representation like described below, how to come up with the hash function for that?

```
struct node {
      int val;
      node *left;
      node *right; 
};
```

Edit: By similar tree, I mean that they have the same values in all the respective nodes. So, compare function will be using the actual trees to compare rather than memory address of root.

Comment: Why do you need a hash function? The pointer/memory location should be sufficient--every object is considered unique. If you don't want them to be unique, then it's up to you to decide what logic you need. You might also want to tag a language... I assume C?

Comment: Updated the question. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your update, it seems your hash funtion is `return val` then, no?

Comment: No, I guess . Suppose two trees which are not similar but still they can have same value of root node.

Comment: Oh, you want to hash the whole tree and check for equality based on all of the nodes in it, as well as their ordering?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

If you can use boost, you can use its `boost::hash_combine` function to mix the hash values. Otherwise, you can write a simple function to do that. You can see a simple recursive function to compute the hash of a tree.

```
struct node 
{
   int val;
   node *left;
   node *right;
};

template <typename T>
size_t hash_combine(std::size_t s, const T & n)
{
   s ^= std::hash<T>()(n) + 0x9e3779b9 + (s << 6) + (s >> 2);

   return s;
}

size_t get_hash(const node & n)
{
   if ((n.left == nullptr) && (n.right == nullptr))
   {
      return std::hash<int>()(n.val);
   }
   else if (n.left == nullptr)
   {
      return hash_combine(get_hash(*n.right), std::hash<int>()(n.val));
   }
   else if (n.right == nullptr)
   {
      return hash_combine(get_hash(*n.left), std::hash<int>()(n.val));
   }
   else
   {
      size_t s = std::hash<int>()(n.val);
      s = hash_combine(s, get_hash(*n.right));
      s = hash_combine(s, get_hash(*n.left));

     return s;
   }
}


namespace std
{
   template <>
   struct hash<node>
   {
      std::size_t operator()(const node & n) const
      {
         return ::get_hash(n);
      }
   };
} // std
```